# how to check if a AAAI proceeding is indexed by scopus

Tags: indexing, scopus

I have a paper in the SoCS conference which proceeding is edited by AAAI. How can I check if the proceeding is indexed by scopus?

Thank's

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Look in Scopus for it.
From https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/scopus/contact-sales , section "Help with Scopus"

> Use our free Scopus Preview to get a complete list of titles indexed
> in Scopus and access to Scopus metrics

Scopus is a product. Ask the product creator directly.